# Async and await skipping tasks

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, kinect

Alright so previously, my question was close in less than 3 minutes so I can't even add on details if I wanted.

So here it is again, this time with codes. So the problem I have now is this. My program will tilt my kinect to -15 degrees, take a screenshot and then move it to 0 degrees. Problem here is that it will skip some codes.

```
private async void DangerScreenshotFunction()
    {
        kinect.ElevationAngle = -15;
        var hiddenTimerTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { Thread.Sleep(3000); });
        await hiddenTimerTask;//These 3 lines works

        var TiltTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            string path = TakeImage(0);
            imageOne = PathToMemory(path);
            ImageComparision(imageOne, imageDB);
            imageOne = null;
        });
        await TiltTask;//This whole part is SKIPPED

        kinect.ElevationAngle = 0;
        var returnToOrigin = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { Thread.Sleep(2000); });
        await returnToOrigin;//This part works.

    }
```

This worked before without any asyncs or await. Is there a issue here?

Comment: How are you invoking your `DangerScreenshotFunction` method? As far as I understand, you are doing all the `await`:ing inside your method, and  you are not returning any data that is asynchronously dependent. Perhaps you should refactor so that the result of the `ImageComparison` is returned by your `DangerScreenshotFunction` method?

Comment: I didn't get any return data because most of the variables are global. The funny thing here is that it works on and off. Sometimes when I reboot, it works. Sometime after that, it doesn't. Weird huh?

Comment: Is any of the methods `TakeImage`, `PathToMemory` or `ImageComparision` asynchronous? Or for that matter the `ElevationAngle` property`?

Comment: None of them are async. ElevationAngle is a system property so no.

Comment: Are `TakeImage`, `PathToMemory`, and `ImageComparision` capable of running correctly on a thread pool thread?

Comment: Yeah. But problem is that it works normally, but doesn't work with timers.

Comment: Is DangerScreenshotFunction being awaited? If not, you may be getting undesired exception behaviour in TiltTask.

Comment: @user1334774 Why have you separated your method into three (sequential) tasks? Wouldn't it be enough to have one task and wait for this single task to complete?

Comment: @DanielNolan: It's not being awaited. Its being called normally. Anders: If I joined everything together, ElevationAngle property will return me a InvalidOperationError.